# How to generate extenstion change .aidl to .java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, aidl

I know that Eclipse generate extenstion change [src/ ~.aidl] to [gen/ ~.java] automatic.

but, i want to know that how to generate extenstion change .aidl to .java automatic in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse doesn't just change the file extension; it uses an Android SDK tool called `aidl` to create a whole Java class based on the information within the `.aidl` file.

There's documentation on the [aidl format here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) and it is compiled to classes based on [`IBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html).

The source code for the aidl tool itself can be [found here](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/tools/aidl/), but really the best way to understand exactly what it does is to look at one of the generated .java files.